# JSONAPI boolean attributes

Tags: specifications, json-api

When you work with [JSONAPI](http://jsonapi.org/), how you handle the boolean attributes?

For example:

```
{
    "type": "motors",
    "id": "1",
    "attributes": {
      "name": "V8",
      "working": "true"
    }
}
```

or

```
{
    "type": "motors",
    "id": "1",
    "attributes": {
      "name": "V8",
      "working": "1"
    }
}
```

Also, I think this is better solution, but don't work with the official specification:

```
{
    "type": "motors",
    "id": "1",
    "attributes": {
      "name": "V8",
      "working": true
    }
}
```

Comment: I don't think you can get away without enclosing the value between double quotes; "true" should work fine (provided you'll be mapping to a model with an appropriate bool property), and it's also more explicit than "1"

Comment: jsonapi specification don't say "attributes allways like a string?"

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The first two examples represent `strings` and the last example represents `a boolean` value on JSON (http://www.json.org/)

**From the spec:**

A value can be a `string in double quotes`, or a `number`, or `true` or `false` or `null`, or `an object` or `an array`. These structures can be nested.`

If you really want `a boolean` then use the last example.

`JSON:API` do not say anything about it because, the specification itself is on top of `JSON` (inherit all the `JSON` specification)